# Selenium Python Driver can't find the button in Canva

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.canva.com/en_gb/login/")

#fullscreen
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

#login
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/main/div[6]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/input")
button.send_keys("xegepor496@566dh.com")

#password
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/main/div[6]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/input")
button.send_keys("test12345test")

#log in
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/main/div[6]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/form/button")
button.click()

#create project
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/header/div/header/div[5]/div/button")))
button.click()

#custom size
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button")))
button.click()

#dimensions click
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/button")))
button.click()

#choose dimensions in inches
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/button")))
button.click()

time.sleep(3)

#width
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")))
button.send_keys("17")

time.sleep(1)

#height
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")))
button.send_keys("11")

#create new project
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 70)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/button")))
button.click()

time.sleep(3)

#uploaded
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/aside/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/aside/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button").click()
```

I want click on some button in Canva, but driver can't find this.
And later I want upload file to Canva by sendkeys, but I can't find proper input type in source code.

My problem begins with last button under #uploaded, I tried every xpath near this button, but maybe I do some stupid mistake.

There is new example Canva account specifically for this test.

This script aims to log in, create new project with some dimensions, and later I want go to the Uploaded (second option on the left menu).

And later I want to upload some picture to the project from my hard disc by sendkeys method, but I can't find proper input type element in web source code.

Error I got with Uploaded button:

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/aside/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/aside/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Comment: Maybe you use  find_elements_by_xpath instead of find_element_by_xpath?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.find_elements` which returns a list and not just a single element. So you are essentially trying to click a 'list' (as the error suggests) you should use `.find_element'` (theres no 's'). This will return a single element.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/aside/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/aside/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button").click()
```

Comment: Actually, right - there were elementS, thanks. But still, after change on find element driver can't find this button. I have this error:                                                                               raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/aside/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/aside/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button"}